# multi-step availability step not running in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a multi-step availability test in application insights which is using custom WebTestRequest Plugin. The test doesnt seem to be running in application insights, do I need to do anything different when using custom WebTestRequest Plugin.

Please advise.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom plugins are not supported by AI. Only the out-of-the box plugins shipped with Visual Studio 2003 and up are supported.

Comment: @Yousuf so you don't see any data points at all? If that's the case, I'd recommend opening a support ticket.

Comment: yes, I am not seeing any data points. Seems like it is not supported, I have found this thread on  msdn forums - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/28822dff-1a68-446c-8ec2-017a90cd922e/is-a-custom-webtestrequestplugin-supported-in-a-multistep-availability-test-in-application-insigths?forum=ApplicationInsights

Comment: I completely missed the fact you were trying to use a custom plugin. I thought it was a default one. Yes, custom plugins are definitely not supported. Edited my original answer.